# Is penis size correlated with size or expense of vehicle purchased?

Tags: personal-finance

There is a common joke/insinuation that those with a small penis are likely to buy either larger or more expensive vehicles to 'compensate' for their small penis.

Have any studies demonstrated such a correlation actually occurring?

Comment: I am surprised that this apparently has not been asked before.

Comment: @seth me too.  I looked for awhile expecting it to have been before I posted this, and was still half afraid It would be closed as a duplicate because I missed the question somehow

Comment: If a source for the claim is required to show notability, you could use [this](http://kbat.com/survey-says-42-of-guys-who-drive-sports-cars-have-a-small-penis/) (although this claim might be acceptable without source, as it is rather well known).

Comment: tim, yeah, no need for a source.

Comment: **any studies demonstrated such a correlation**. I am curious how do you expect this study to be conducted? A lab in university post an ad: "Looking for people to participate in a study. You need to earn more than 200k per year and have a car which costs at least 120k. Be ready to prove both statements and we will also measure the size of your penis. By the way, we will give you 20$ for participation".

Comment: @SalvadorDali Hey I'm happy to show off how small my penis is for 20 dollars!  Of course my car cost 11K and I'm only a little over half of the way to the salary department so I guess I don't get the money.  No fair! ;P

Comment: I can't admit that you're going to get any accurate data on this because nobody is going to own up to having a small penis.

Comment: I don't think there are any large-scale studies that actually measure penile length, so the chances of them also taking into account car size too are slim. I've only ever seen surveys that take into account what people claim, which is obviously not even remotely reliable.

Comment: You could do a "measurement" in hospitals after accidents.  That way you'd know the car and the "size".  You would be selecting from a pool containing a disproportionate number of bad drivers though...

Comment: @mcottle and why would hospitals agree to provide a very sensitive data, protected in many countries, where enough people can afford 120k car? For a dubious 'study'? Also this will most probably will not help a lot because not a lot of 120+k in the accidents and also you are measuring size of people who prone to near kill themselves in a car accident. To dsollen, sorry I am not interested in such activity, try asking some people in your neighborhood :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz - where's your obligatory "Correlation does not imply causation" comment? :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because jokes are off-topic ... this isn't a claim to be taken literally. If I interpret or explain the joke to find a literal claim, I assume its saying "penis size" is used as a proxy for "sexual attractiveness" or even "sexual enjoyment" which can includes e.g. wealth, confidence, etc.

Comment: @ChrisW  No, it's literally a small penis.  It's [Freudian](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/beyond-freud/201301/penis-size-consideration-fantasy-and-reality).  You know, the same guy who said all women have complexes because they envy men for having penises.  In [Freudian quackery](https://www.lgbtqnation.com/2016/06/remember-freud-said-men-obsess-guns-small-genitals/) a man with a small penis is more "effeminate" and needs to compensate.  Women, with no penises, have to compensate even more.  I say quackery because most studies find the opposite.  Women are less likely to compensate.